# First character in Textbox to upper case on Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I'm using a textbox on my Windows Phone 8 app. I want that the first character which will be insert by the user will be in upper case.

```
        if (str.Length == 1)
            str = str.ToUpper();
```

I've tried to handle TextChanged event on Textbox with the above code, but the cursor will move to the first position, so I can't insert more text at the right place.

So, how can I make the first letter of textbox to upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `InputScope` property to `Text`. The first character will automatically be inserted in upper case, and the `TextBox` will get auto-correction, suggestions, and emoticons.

```
<TextBox InputScope="Text" />
```